# Less files not compiled

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

Using Play 2.1.4 RC2 and my problem is that my `style.less` is not being compiled. I keep getting `404 Not Found` errors.

I have the following setup (sorry for the formatting):

- MyApp

  - app

    - nl

      - myapp

        - assets

          - css

            - style.less

I am not seeing what mistake I have made here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory((base / "app" / "assets" / "css" * "*.less"))
```

Stick that in your Build.scala main project .settings(...) block

No need for packages in assets/